# Headless Browser for Internet Explorer in java

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, htmlunit, headless-browser

An application which can only support IE and i have to do **screen scraping** of it. I have tried with htmlUnit and selenium htmlUnit driver which did not worked out for me. I want to know, is there any headless browser api available in java for IE browser. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [JExplorer](https://www.teamdev.com/jexplorer) Java library that allows embedding MS IE web browser control into Java AWT/Swing application and use MS IE functionality directly from Java code.

For example:

```
import com.teamdev.jexplorer.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jexplorer.BrowserFeatures;
import com.teamdev.jexplorer.BrowserMode;
import com.teamdev.jexplorer.dom.*;
import com.teamdev.jexplorer.event.NavigationAdapter;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * The sample demonstrates how to get all elements with tag A and 
 * print their text content.
 */
public class DOMGetElementsSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BrowserFeatures.enableBrowserMode(BrowserMode.IE11);
        Browser browser = new Browser();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(browser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.addNavigationListener(new NavigationAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mainDocumentCompleted(Browser browser, String url) {
                DOMDocument document = browser.getDocument();
                DOMNodeList elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
                int length = elements.getLength();
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    DOMNode domNode = elements.item(i);
                    if (domNode instanceof DOMElement) {
                        DOMElement element = (DOMElement) domNode;
                        System.out.println("Text Content: " + 
                                element.getTextContent());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        browser.navigate("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Vladimir i am ignorant about JExplorer, so i have one question. Does  JExplorer provides an API that allows to invoke pages, fill out forms, click links etc for browser testing.

Comment: Yes, you can load web page, wait until it's loaded completely, find required HTML element on the web page, modify HTML element, click it, etc.